# Get last_inserted_id - PHP - Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Is there a way to insert data in two tables at the same time and then at the same moment to get the id from first table and insert it to the second table in my field named user_id let's say. I tried something with this but it's not working. Am I missing something? I want to do this because I need to have same ids of the same records in the two tables to make an update. Thanks.

```php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
$table = 'tst_test';
$data = array( 
          'user_id' => $user_id, 
          'username' => $_POST['fname'], 
          'email' => $_POST['email'], 
          'telefon' => $_POST['phone_number']
); 
$format = array('%s','%s', '%s', '%s'); 
$send_data = $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `$wpdb->insert_id` after `$wpdb->insert(_)`, this will return the last inserted id of the the object, then you can use the same for the second record.

For more information on the DB operations of [Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

No such mechanism is supported by MySQL, but you can achieve it by

1. Insert the data in first table, the user_id column of this table must be auto increment

   ```
   INSERT INTO table1 (user_id, username, email, telefon) VALUES (NULL, $_POST['fname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone_number'])
   ```
2. Get auto increment id of last step's insert statment

   ```
   $userID = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
   ```
3. Use the userID from last step to insert in second table

   ```
   INSERT INTO table2 (user_id, username, email, telefon) VALUES ($userID, $_POST['fname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone_number'])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the stored procedure try this code.

```
CREATE TABLE a
( user_id   INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
, a_text CHAR(12));

CREATE TABLE b
( b_id   INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
, user_id   INT UNSIGNED 
, b_text CHAR(12));

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE double_insert
( input_a CHAR(12), input_b CHAR(12))
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO a VALUES (NULL, input_a);  
  INSERT INTO b VALUES (NULL, last_insert_id(), input_b);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

if you are using PDO the call like this hope this will help you.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
```